# System generator frequency issue

Tags: fpga, xilinx-system-generator

I have a design in Xilinx system generator which meets maximum frequency of **50MHz** (I found this from **Timing and Power Analyzer** of **System generator**). However, my FPGA board offers **100MHz** clock rate. How could I solve this issue? (is there any way like creating a divided clock which can be assigned to the **FPGA clock period** of **clocking options** in **system generator token**?)

Answer (score 1):

Im not an expert on this but a little research (30seconds) on our favorite search enginge brought me to someone who had the exact same problem 5 years ago. I think you can go on from there, eventhough the frequency is a little different.
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t294219-frequency-divider.html